# Javascript validation for email making issues

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

In my project, I am doing a JS validation for registration purpose. But the validation fails after the email validation. Upto the email validation, it works fine. But after that it is not showing any alerts for rest of validation code.

```
function signup() {

    var signupFullName        = $("#signup-full-name");
    var signupName            = $("#signup-login-name");
    var signupEmailAddress    = $("#signup-email-address");
    var signupPhoneNumber     = $("#signup-phone-number");
    var signupPassword        = $("#signup-password");
    var signupConfirmPassword = $("#signup-confirm-password");
    var signupAcceptTerms     = $("#signup-accept-terms");

    if (signupFullName[0].value == "" || signupFullName[0].value == null) {

        //alert("Please enter a valid full name.");
        alert("Please enter your full name");
        signupFullName[0].focus();

        return false;

    } else if (signupName[0].value == "" || signupName[0].value == null) {

        //alert("Please enter a valid login name.");
        alert("Please enter your login name.");
        signupName[0].focus();

        return false;

    } else if (signupEmailAddress[0].value == "" || signupEmailAddress[0].value == null) {

        //alert("Please enter a valid email address.");   
        alert("Please enter your email address.");   
        signupEmailAddress[0].focus();

        return false;

    } 
    else if(signupEmailAddress[0].value != "")  // problem in this section
    {
        email=signupEmailAddress[0].value;

       if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/).test(email))  
       {
           alert("Please enter a valid email address.");   
            signupEmailAddress[0].focus();
            return false;
       }
    }
    else if (signupPhoneNumber[0].value == "" || signupPhoneNumber[0].value == null) {

       // alert("Please enter a valid phone number.");\
        alert("Please enter your phone number.");
        signupPhoneNumber[0].focus();

        return false;

    } else if (signupPassword[0].value == "" || signupPassword[0].value == null) {

        //alert("Please enter a valid password.");
        alert("Please enter your password.");
        signupPassword[0].focus();

        return false;

    } else if (signupConfirmPassword[0].value == "" || signupConfirmPassword[0].value == null) {

        alert("Please confirm the password.");
        signupConfirmPassword[0].focus();

        return false;

    } else if (signupPassword[0].value != signupConfirmPassword[0].value) {

        //alert("Please confirm the password.");
        alert("Password mismatch");
        signupConfirmPassword[0].focus();

        return false;

    } else if ($("#signup-accept-terms")[0].checked == false) {

        alert("Please accept the terms and conditions.");
        return false;

    } else {        
        alert("Done");
        return false;

    }

}
```

HTML form code:

```
<form name="signup-form" id="signup-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $site_path; ?>/register" class="form-1"  onsubmit="signup();return false;">
                    <p class="field">
                        <a href="<?php echo $root_path; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $theme_path;?>/images/logo.png"/>
                        </a>
                        <h4 style="margin-top:10px;color:#208CCD;">Signup</h4>
                        <br/>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="signup-full-name" id="signup-full-name" placeholder="Full name">
                        <i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="signup-login-name" id="signup-login-name" placeholder="User name">
                        <i class="icon-signin icon-large"></i>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="signup-email-address" id="signup-email-address" placeholder="Email address">
                        <i class="icon-inbox icon-large"></i>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="signup-phone-number" id="signup-phone-number" placeholder="Phone number">
                        <i class="icon-phone icon-large"></i>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field">
                        <input type="password" name="signup-password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Password">
                        <i class="icon-lock icon-large"></i>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <input type="password" name="signup-confirm-password" id="signup-confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm password">
                        <i class="icon-lock icon-large"></i>
                    </p>
                    <p class="field">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="signup-accept-terms" id="signup-accept-terms" style="margin-top:10px;color:#B3B3B3">
                            I accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a> and the <a href="#">Privacy Policies</a>
                        </input>
                    </p>
                    <p class="submit">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i></button>
                    </p>
                </form>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browsers dev console?

Comment: @blackn1ght..no any errors are shown

Comment: What do you mean by the email validation is failing? Are you receiving an alert "Please enter an email address"?

Comment: yes..If I enter a invalid email the alert will show.After that when I give a valid email and leave fields for password as null, the validation for password won't work. No any alert will be shown after that.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it it's because you use if/else to check validity of the fields.

So the code picks one error at a time - if any. While you should have something like a for-loop across all the fields you want to validate
I mean it picks this

```
} else if(signupEmailAddress[0].value != "") {
```

but does not fall into inner check anymore

```
 if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/).test(email))
```

because email is ok now

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this statement:

```
else if(signupEmailAddress[0].value != "")
```

Because the email field contains text, this rule is evaluated as true and so the rest of the else if blocks won't be executed.

I'd consider changing the else if's to be individual if statements so that they won't stop each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the **return false** statements inside if condition. Inside validation function, at the end you have to return false if any of the validation fails. Here's an example to do it:

```
var result = true;
if(condition 1){ // if condition 1 fails, make result = false;

}

if(condition 1){ // if condition 2 fails, make result = false;

}

if(condition 1){ // if condition 3 fails, make result = false;

}

return result;  // After all validations, result result
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your correction place with this code....

```
else if(signupEmailAddress[0].value != "" && !(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/).test(signupEmailAddress[0].value))  // problem in this section
    {
          alert("Please enter a valid email address.");   
          signupEmailAddress[0].focus();
          return false;
    }
```